# Error when bootstrapping large n with boot package (error: integer overflow)

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

Why can I not bootstrap a statistic with large n using the `boot` package? Although, 150,000 obs is not large, so I don't know why this isn't working.

**Example**

```
library(boot)

bs <- boot(rnorm(150000), sum, R = 1000)
bs

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = rnorm(150000), statistic = sum, R = 1000)


Bootstrap Statistics :
WARNING: All values of t1* are NA
```

**Error Message**

> In statistic(data, i[r, ], ...) : integer overflow - use
>   sum(as.numeric(.))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `boot()` as documented (which is, admittedly, surprisingly complex). From `?boot`:

> In all other cases ‘statistic’
>             must take at least two arguments.  The first argument passed
>             will always be the original data.  The second will be a
>             vector of indices, frequencies or weights which define the
>             bootstrap sample.

I think you want:

```
bsum <- function(x,i) sum(x[i])
bs <- boot(rnorm(150000), bsum, R = 1000)
```

I haven't taken the time to figure out what `boot()` is *actually* doing in your case - almost certainly not what you want though.

Comment: Ah! I forgot it needs an index `i`.  Thanks!